# How to add only Frame rate mode using FFMPEG for an AVI file

Tags: ffmpeg

For one of our 3rd party tool to work we need our AVI files should contain the Frame rate mode                          : Variable Using FFMPEG is it possible to add this tag in the video section?

Tried different commands like

```
ffmpeg -i Input.avi -r 30 Output.avi

 ffmpeg -i Input.avi -vf "fps=30,settb=1/1000"  Output.avi

ffmpeg -i Input.avi -r 30 -fps_mode vbr Output.avi
```

But none of them inserting the "Frame rate Mode" tag.

Expected structure is:

```
mediainfo Input.avi 
General
Complete name                            : Input.avi
Format                                   : AVI
Format/Info                              : Audio Video Interleave
Format settings                          : BitmapInfoHeader / WaveFormatEx
File size                                : 2.17 MiB
Duration                                 : 30 s 613 ms
Overall bit rate                         : 596 kb/s
Frame rate                               : 30.000 FPS
Writing application                      : Lavf57.19.100

Video
ID                                       : 0
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L4
Format settings                          : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : H264
Duration                                 : 30 s 33 ms
Bit rate                                 : 447 kb/s
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
**Frame rate mode                          : Variable**
Frame rate                               : 30.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.007
Stream size                              : 1.60 MiB (74%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 148
```